# Is there a way to refile subtrees to other files in org-mode?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I would like to transfer my tasks from an inbox-type file to several more specific files. The command org-refile gives the option to refile subtrees under other nodes, but it does not seem to be able to refile it under other nodes in a different file.

How could I refile subtrees to different files?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to improve the quality of your question. Then check the [Help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) to see what questions you can ask. Show your attempts you have tried and the problem/error messages you get from your attempts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the documentation for the variable `org-refile-targets`. It allows you to specify a list of files to consider for refiling.

Comment: See http://www.johnborwick.com/2019/02/23/org-todo-setup.html for an example as well

Comment: `org-refile-targets` is the variable to set, as **éric** says. Note you can set it to specific files, or  your agenda files, and include how far down the hierarchy you want it to look for nodes.